# Why does my SELECT statement show a duplicate record?

Tags: mysql

I am having some trouble overcoming this error. When I perform the SELECT statement in its entirety, a duplicate message is shown.

The code is:

```
SELECT students.first_name, last_name ,entries.subject_id, subject_name, level_of_entry
FROM students, subjects , entries
WHERE subjects.subject_id=entries.subject_id
AND students.student_id=entries.student_id
AND exam_board='ocr';
```

[This is what happens after that code is processed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45ApG.png)

[These are the tables which the data is coming from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFvnK.png)

Is there a way to stop the duplication or delete one of the duplicated rows?

The row that is duplicated is row 6 and 7; the one with Zeynnata Rein.

Thanks for the help in advance!!!

PS: Sorry for the spelling error for Physics

Comment: Please update your question and add  the text  instead of img  .. so who want answer  avoid to type your code  ..

Comment: The code **must** be in the **question itself**.

Comment: i don't see  any duplicated record .. please exaplain better you problem

Comment: No duplication is in your result. Each row is uniquely differs.

Comment: There is for row 6 and 7

Answer (score 0):

you have to use group by on student_id

Answer (score 0):

Because you aren't joining the tables it's returning all matching combinations.  Try explicit joins:

```
SELECT st.first_name, st.last_name, e.subject_id, su.subject_name, su.level_of_entry
FROM students st
LEFT JOIN entries e
ON st.student_id = e.student_id
LEFT JOIN subjects su
ON e.subject_id = su.subject_id
WHERE su.exam_board = 'ocr';
```

Comment: Ok I'll try that

Comment: Edited and fixed an error in the query. Try it now @Mario

Comment: Its to do with the abbreviations like "st" and "e" saying that no such field exists @Carl Sanders

Comment: Fixed another error - this time in the 'Where' line.  Can you try again?